Shim boot loader: System is compromised when using certificate, but not with hash
I am trying to boot a Linux kernel with efi stub enabled using Red Hat's Shim https://github.com/rhboot/shim.
I can boot the system if I enroll the hash of my efi stub (selecting GRUBX64.EFI), but shim says the system is compromised when i enroll its certificate. I'd like to use a certificate so I can update without having to re-enroll.
Error message on boot:
EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled.
Bootloader has not verified loaded image.
System is compromised.  halting.

Shim version: 15.8-3, extracted from Fedora rpm (signed by Microsoft).
Compiling Linux 6.9.7 (Buildroot) with EFI_STUB=y. Outputs bzImage.
Adding SBAT using script from https://github.com/rhboot/shim/issues/376#issuecomment-1628004034:
pe-add-sections.py -s .sbat sbat.csv -z .sbat -i bzImage -o bzImage.sbat

where sbat.csv:
sbat,1,SBAT Version,sbat,1,https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/main/SBAT.md
rescue,1,ABC,rescue,1,https://example.com

Signing:
openssl req \
        -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -nodes -days 36500 -outform DER \
        -keyout "mok.priv" \
        -out "mok.der" \
        -subj "/CN=Rescue/"

openssl x509 -in mok.der -inform DER -outform PEM -out mok.pem

sbsign --key mok.priv --cert mok.pem --output bzImage.signed bzImage.sbat

Then using genimage (https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage) to create img:
# file genimage.cfg

image efi-part.vfat {
    vfat {
        file EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI {
            image = "shimx64.efi"
        }

        file EFI/BOOT/MMX64.EFI {
            image = "mmx64.efi"
        }

        file EFI/BOOT/GRUBX64.EFI {
            image = "bzImage.signed"
        }

        file MOK.DER {
            image = "mok.der"
        }
    }
    size = 16M
}

image disk.img {
    hdimage {
        partition-table-type = "gpt"
    }

    partition boot {
        image = "efi-part.vfat"
        partition-type-uuid = U
        offset = 32K
        bootable = true
    }
}

genimage -c genimage.cfg # Outputs disk.img

I have verified that GRUBX64.EFI isn't changed by genimage with sbverify --cert mok.pem GRUBX64.EFI
Tested by writing to USB (dd ...) and booting on Surface Go 2, and in the following vm, with the same results:
#!/bin/bash

set -Eeuxo pipefail

MACHINE_NAME="test"
SSH_PORT="5555"
OVMF_CODE="/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.ms.fd"
OVMF_VARS_ORIG="/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd"
OVMF_VARS="$(basename "${OVMF_VARS_ORIG}")"

if [ ! -e "${OVMF_VARS}" ]; then
        cp "${OVMF_VARS_ORIG}" "${OVMF_VARS}"
fi

qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -enable-kvm \
        -cpu host -smp cores=1,threads=1 -m 4096 \
        -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 \
        -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 \
        -name "${MACHINE_NAME}" \
    -drive format=raw,file="disk.img" \
        -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::${SSH_PORT}-:22 \
        -vga virtio \
        -machine q35,smm=on \
        -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file="${OVMF_CODE}",readonly=on \
        -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file="${OVMF_VARS}" \
        -global driver=cfi.pflash01,property=secure,value=on \
        $@

I have tried signing with pesign, but it didn't make a difference:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir db
certutil -d db -N --empty-password

efikeygen -d db \
  --self-sign \
  --nickname='Rescue' \
  --common-name='CN=Rescue,OU=xxx,O=xxx,C=US'

certutil -d db -L -n "Rescue" -r > mok.der
pesign --force -s -n db -c "Rescue" -i bzImage.sbat -o bzImage.signed

What am I doing wrong?

Got it. There seem to be a special case for hash-enrolled stuff. Creating the image with ukify worked - almost - like a charm. Now I just need to deal with the warning: "Overlapping PE sections detected. Boot may fail due to image memory corruption!".
Edit: And that was solved by using the latest linuxx64.efi.stub. Now everything works!
#!/bin/bash

LINUX=bzImage
SBAT=@sbat.csv
SB_PRIV_KEY=mok.priv
SB_PUB_KEY=mok.pem

ukify build \
        --linux "$LINUX" \
        --sbat "$SBAT" \
        --sign-kernel \
        --secureboot-private-key "$SB_PRIV_KEY" \
        --secureboot-certificate "$SB_PUB_KEY"

this creates bzImage.efi and that is bootable by Shim with an enrolled certificate.
